# Python Beautiful Soup - finding a string that contains special characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body>BLAR fff11 &pound; </body></html>", 'html.parser')
for z in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('&pound;')):
    print(z)
```

For some reason that returns nothing, however if I change the special characters in both the sample html and my find statement it works:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body>BLAR fff11 pound </body></html>", 'html.parser')
for z in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('pound')):
    print(z)
```

Output is: BLAR fff11 pound

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong, and how I can find strings with special characters in?

Thanks

Comment: Are `&` and `;` possible special characters in regular expressions? At the very least, I'd backslash them

Comment: By default, BeautifulSoup will convert your input `&pound;` into `£`.  If you want to change this, have a look at: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#output-formatters

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a BeautifulSoup object from HTML, HTML entities are converted to the corresponding Unicode characters.

So to search for such a character, use the character itself and not its HTML entity equivalent.  Using the HTML in your example, the below code...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body>BLAR fff11 &pound; </body></html>", 'html.parser')
for z in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('£')):  # Actual '£' character, not '&pound;'
    print(z)
```

...prints:

```
BLAR fff11 £
```

It was possible to bypass this conversion in v3 of BeautifulSoup, but not in v4 (["An incoming HTML or XML entity is always converted into the corresponding Unicode character."](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=encode#entities))

If you want to get the HTML entities back when converting a BeautifulSoup object to a string, that's still possible by [specifying `formatter="html"`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=encode#output-formatters).